# EXTRA_PREVIOUS_SCAN_MODE always returns an error for Android Bluetooth

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth

I'm using the following code to return an object to Cordova when the device's Bluetooth's scan mode changes (i.e. discoverable/not discoverable).

```
cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c,Intent intent){
        JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
        try{
            json.put("current",intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE,BluetoothAdapter.ERROR));
            json.put("previous",intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_SCAN_MODE,BluetoothAdapter.ERROR));
        }catch(JSONException e){
        }
        PluginResult result=new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK,json);
        result.setKeepCallback(true);
        discoverableCallback.sendPluginResult(result); // discoverableCallback is a callbackContext
    }
},new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED));
```

However, `intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_SCAN_MODE,BluetoothAdapter.ERROR)` is always `BluetoothAdapter.ERROR`. I tried setting discoverability on and off several times consecutively and it's always `BluetoothAdapter.ERROR`. How do I make it return the previous scan mode?

Comment: What is inside the intent you are parsing? Try printing out the Key Value pairs via Iterator.

Comment: The intent is to set Bluetooth as discoverable (by other devices). Which variable's key/value pairs do I print?

Comment: this BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_CONNECTION_STATE wont work for you  with required condition ?

Comment: I think your intent is missing the "EXTRA_PREVIOUS_SCAN_MODE" int for some (unknown for now) reason.
Try to debug - and print all the keys in your intent, and see if it's there. If it's not, we will see how to proceed further.
Try this code to write all the data:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/57283cb3f3dad29cb390

Comment: Thanks @Tom, I will try it later when I get home.

Comment: Something came up yesterday, so I tried it today. The only field in the Intent is `android.bluetooth.adapter.extra.SCAN_MODE`, so that's probably the issue. I haven't modified the Intent anywhere in my code.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see in the [AOSP](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/packages/apps/Bluetooth/src/com/android/bluetooth/btservice/AdapterProperties.java) source , `EXTRA_PREVIOUS_SCAN_MODE`is never being used. So I guess the documentation from Google is wrong in this case . If you do search [here](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/search?q=EXTRA_PREVIOUS_SCAN_MODE&defs=&refs=&path=-txt%20-xml%20-%20jar&hist=&project=abi&project=art&project=bionic&project=bootable&project=build&project=cts&project=dalvik&project=developers&project=development&project=device&project=docs&project=external&project=frameworks&project=hardware&project=libcore&project=libnativehelper&project=ndk&project=packages&project=pdk&project=prebuilts&project=sdk&project=system&project=tools) results in no references in the whole source code