# Is it possible to get notified when the ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE timeout expires?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

In my code, I make my device discoverable by using the `REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE` intent. This makes the device discoverable until a certain timeout expires. That timeout can be configured with the `EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION` int field.

However, I haven't found a way to get notified when the timeout expires. I could just start my own timer, but this seems fragile; what if the discoverable state is ended by some other means, for example by user intervention in the Bluetooth settings? It would therefore be useful to somehow be notified by Android that the device is no longer discoverable. Any suggestions? Are there callbacks for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the description of [ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE). It states:

> Applications can also listen for [ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED) for global notification whenever the scan mode changes. For example, an application can be notified when the device has ended discoverability.

Comment: I was using that action before, but it seemingly never worked. I now figured out why: As indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30935424/560774), the documentation seems wrong (or there's a bug in Android) - `EXTRA_PREVIOUS_SCAN_MODE` is always missing. My code was trying to get that, but silently failed, leading to the illusion that the scan mode change was never announced. Now I just look for `EXTRA_SCAN_MODE`, and my code works, thanks.

Comment: Not the first time the docs regarding Bluetooth were wrong... great you figured it out!